# linq results for display in view - How to apply grouping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, grouping

How can I group the results of this query by wl.WishlistID?

```
var projected = (from wl in context.Wishlists.Where(x => x.UserId == 6013)
                     from wli in wl.WishlistItems
                     select new wishListProjection
                    {
                       wlId = wl.WishlistID,
                       wlUserId = (int)wl.UserId,
                       wlDesc = wl.description,
                       wlTitle = wl.Title,
                       wliWishlistItemID = wli.WishlistItemID,
                       wliQtyWanted = (int)wli.QtyWanted,
                       wliPriceWhenAdded = wli.PriceWhenAdded,
                       wliDateAdded = (DateTime)wli.DateAdded,
                       wliQtyBought = (int)wli.QtyBought,
                 }).ToList();
```

This returns the results I want, but I want to be able to iterate over them in the view without repeating the parent-level Wishlist object.
I've tried adding the line:

```
group wl by wl.WishlistID into g
```

But I don't seem to be able to access any properties by using g.[propertyname]

This grouping achieves more or less what I want, but I want to convert the results into a new or anonymous type, rather than return the entire object.

```
var results = context.WishlistItems.GroupBy(x => x.Wishlist).
                Select(group => new { wl = group.Key, items = group.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the properties of `g` because when you do the grouping:

```
group wl by wl.WishlistID into g
```

`g` is of type `IGrouping<typeof(wl.WishlistID),typeof(wl)>`, which is essentially a collection of all `wl`'s with the same key `wl.WishlistID`.  In other words, you cannot access the properties of `g` because `g` is not a single entity, it is a collection of those entities.

For your second grouping you said you would like to create an anonymous type instead of the entire object.  You can do this by doing the selection first and then grouping:

```
var results = context.WishlistItems
                     .Select(x => new { })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyOfProjection)
                     .Select(group => new { wl = group.Key, items = group.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Or, using a nested sub query in your first example:

```
var projected = (from x in
                     (from wl in context.Wishlists.Where(x => x.UserId == 6013)
                      from wli in wl.WishlistItems
                      select new wishListProjection
                      {
                          wlId = wl.WishlistID,
                          wlUserId = (int)wl.UserId,
                          wlDesc = wl.description,
                          wlTitle = wl.Title,
                          wliWishlistItemID = wli.WishlistItemID,
                          wliQtyWanted = (int)wli.QtyWanted,
                          wliPriceWhenAdded = wli.PriceWhenAdded,
                          wliDateAdded = (DateTime)wli.DateAdded,
                          wliQtyBought = (int)wli.QtyBought,
                      })
                 group x by w.wlId into g).ToList();
```

I'm not sure what you mean by iterate without repeating the parent-level Wishlist object because whenever you create a grouping in Linq you will still have to have a nested `foreach` like:

```
foreach (var x in grouping)
{
    x.Key;
    foreach (var y in x)
    {
        y.Property;
    }
}
```